# identify the visitors country:-my code is working perfectly in my local machine. But when i host its not working please check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am Trying to identify the visitors country.My code is working perfectly in my local machine.when i host its not working. How can i fix this issue. Please check my code

```
var country = '';
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
country = data.address.country;
alert(country)
});
```

Comment: 1. closing `});` of `$(function () {` is missed so add it. 2. put `var country = '';` inside `$(function () {`

Comment: Also what error it is giving  in console when you hosted it and try to run it through browser.?

Comment: hay @Alive to Die its right i got ans. Where is your ans to vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes needed:-

1.Closing `});` of `$(function () {` is missed so add it.

2.Put `var country = '';` inside `$(function () {`

***Working example:-***

```js
$(function () {
 var country = ''; //put it inside to prevent yourself from out-of-scope problem at any time

 $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
  country = data.address.country;
  console.log(country); //alert will work also
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note:- This will work only when jQuery library added before it.

You can do it like below too:-

```
$(function () {
  $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
   var country = data.address.country;
   console.log(country); //alert will work also
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are getting cross domain issue while hosting it.Try to use $ajax like this way..

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  success: function(data){
  // we make a successful JSONP call!
  }
});
```

Comment: @ Ritwika Das . I got the ans. any way thx for your feed back

Comment: welcome.. :-) but  may i know how u solved it.. is it a cross domain issue?

Comment: my varible declaration was not correct . now i added var country = data.address.country;  like this :)